# Show a question when the console command parameter is missing

Tags: symfony

I'm writing a console command in Symfony.

I can't understand if it is possible to show the question I've added (Who do you want to greet?) when the user doesn't specify the name parameter.

```
class GreetCommand extends Command
{
    // ...

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('greet:someone')
            ->setDescription('Greet somebody')
            ->addArgument('name', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Who do you want to greet?')
        ;
    }
}
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $year = $input->getArgument('name');
...
```

At the moment if I run the **bin/console greet:someone** command I'm getting just this error:

> Not enough arguments (missing: "name").
> greet:someone

Comment: "year" argument and "name" are the same? Do you want add year parameter optional only?

Comment: Sorry, I have deleted "year" now, the only parameter is "name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Symfony Style object could help you to do this.

First change your argument to be optionnal instead of required.

```
protected function configure()
{
    $this
        ->setName('greet:someone')
        ->setDescription('Greet somebody')
        ->addArgument('name', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Who do you want to greet?')
    ;
}
```

Then you could use the SymfonyStyle object to help you to ask interactivelly the question :

```
// Use this method to instantiate a SymfonyStyle
protected function initialize(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $this->io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $name = $input->getArgument('name');
    if (!$name) {
        $name = $this->io->ask('Who do you want to greet?');
    }
...
```

The ask method take a second argument to give a default value to name, and a thrid one to validate the user input with a callable. They are both optionnals.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/style.html#user-input-methods